# How can I create a tuple instance from another tuple instance that statically selects only indices that satisfy a certain type rule?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Suppose that I have a base type and some derived types:

```
struct base {};
struct d1 : base {};
struct d2 : base {};
```

Suppose that I create a tuple like:

```
std::tuple<double, d1, d2, int> t(1.0, d1(), d2(), 1);
```

Is it possible to use meta/runtime programming to generate:

```
template<typename T>
using my_predicate = std::is_base_of<base, T>;

std::tuple<d1, d2> t_derived = filter(t, my_predicate);
```

I have looked at an answer on stack exchange that would let me define the new type, but I haven't figured out how to select the runtime components from the original tuple. The stack exchange post is here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115740/filtering-variadic-template-arguments

Comment: So what about that post did you find confusing? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: And your answer is "yes, it is possible".

Comment: Starting point: you have to know what the index of the types that match your type predicate are.

Comment: If you want an alternative method, look at my previous to this comment answer.  In it I define a function `tupler`.  Now write code to filter `index_sequences` based on some predicate, feed the filtered sequence to tupler, and use it to extract the elements you want from a source tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
template <typename TupleOfIntegralConstant>
struct as_sequence;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct as_sequence<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::index_sequence<Ts::value...>;
};

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename Tuple, typename Seq>
struct make_filtered_sequence;

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
struct make_filtered_sequence<Pred, Tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = typename as_sequence<decltype(std::tuple_cat(
           std::conditional_t<
             Pred<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>::value,
             std::tuple<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>>,
             std::tuple<>>{}...))>::type;
};

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
auto filter_impl(const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
-> std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>
{
    return {std::get<Is>(t)...};
}

template <template <typename> class Pred, typename Tuple>
auto filter(const Tuple& t)
{
    using filtered_seq = typename make_filtered_sequence<Pred, Tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>>::type;

    return filter_impl(t, filtered_seq());
}
```

Idea is to create a filtered sequence, and then use `std::tuple_element_t` and `std::get` with that sequence.